# Reducing an ideal to an ideal generated by fewer elements.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

For $d=-31$,  and $I=(2, 1/2 +\sqrt{-31}/2)$ I've been told that $I\cdot\overline{I}=(2)$

I've written $I\cdot\overline{I}= (4, 1-\sqrt{-31} , 1+\sqrt{-31}, 8) $

In what ways am I allowed to reduce this to show it is generated by just the element 2?

Comment: What's the ring?

Comment: Might be $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-31}]$.  But also quite possibly the ring of algebraic integers in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{-31}]$ which is $\Bbb Z\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-31}}{2}\right]$

Comment: @GregoryGrant $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-31}}{2}\right]$ makes the most sense by the elements of $I$ and that $-31\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Comment: Hint: If an ideal is principal then the norm of the generator must divide the norms of all elements in the ideal.

Comment: Of all the elements in the *ideal*, I would say.

Comment: What do you denote $\overline I$?

Comment: @Bernard I'm assuming that it's the conjugate under the Galois action of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-31}]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $2$ is in your ideal because $$(1-\sqrt{-31})+(1+\sqrt{-31})=2.$$  Also, note that $2\mid 4$ and $2\mid 8$, so $I\cdot \overline{I}=\langle 1+\sqrt{-31},2\rangle$ (you can get $1-\sqrt{-31}$ easily because $2-(1+\sqrt{-31})=1-\sqrt{-31})$.

Finally, since $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{-31}}{2}$ is in your ring, $2\mid 1+\sqrt{-31}$.  Therefore, $I\cdot\overline{I}=\langle 2\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\ w = (1\!+\!\sqrt{-31})/2.\,$ Then $\,\color{#c00}{w\bar w  = 8}\,$ and $\, \color{#0a0}{w+\bar w =1}\,$ hence

$\qquad\ \ I\bar I = (2,w)(2,\bar w) = (4,\color{#c00}8,2w,2\bar w) = 2(2,4,\color{#0a0}{w,\bar w}) = (2)$